# Delete Apex Job submitted by User

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex

How do I delete Apex job submitted by a particular user?  Below is what I found online but this script will delete all apex job with status = queued.

Thanks in advance.

```
   //ApexClass apxClass = [SELECT Id FROM ApexClass WHERE Name = 'myScriptName'];
//List<AsyncApexJob> lstJobs = [SELECT Id FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Status = 'Queued' AND ApexClassId = :apxClass.Id];

List<AsyncApexJob> lstJobs = [SELECT Id FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Status = 'Queued'];

for(AsyncApexJob job : lstJobs) {
   try {
      System.abortJob(job.Id);
   } catch(Exception ex ) {
      System.debug(ex);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CreatedById is the submitter of the job. You can filter on this field just as any other filterable field:

```
AsyncApexJob[] jobsFromUser = [SELECT Id FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Status = 'Queued' AND CreatedById = :selectedUserId];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<AsyncApexJob> lstJobs = [SELECT Id FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Status = 'Queued' AND CreatedById = : userId];
for(AsyncApexJob job : lstJobs) {
   try {
      System.abortJob(job.Id);
   } catch(Exception ex ) {
      System.debug(ex);
   }
}
```